# Habilitar EditText en base a la opcion de un Spinner

Tags: java, android, edittext, spinner

En resumen, quiero que cuando el usuario seleccione incorrecto se habilite su respectivo `EditText` para enviar los datos corregidos de sus respectivos campos y que una vez que están llenos todos los `EditText` me envié a la siguiente `activity`

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Spinner;

public class datosDelDomicilio extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private String[] opc;
private String sT;
protected Spinner sD;
protected Spinner sS;
protected Spinner sL;
protected Spinner sM;
protected Spinner sCo;
protected Spinner sCa;
protected Spinner sNe;
protected Spinner sNi;
protected EditText etD;
protected EditText etNi;
protected EditText etNe;
protected EditText etCa;
protected EditText etCo;
protected EditText etM;
protected EditText etL;
protected EditText etS;
private ArrayAdapter<String> aaOption;
public datosDelDomicilio(String[] opc) {
    this.opc = opc;
}
public datosDelDomicilio(String sT) {
    this.sT = sT;
}
public datosDelDomicilio(ArrayAdapter<String> aaOption) {
    this.aaOption = aaOption;
}
public datosDelDomicilio(Spinner sD, Spinner sS, Spinner sL, Spinner sM, Spinner sCo, Spinner sCa, Spinner sNe, Spinner sNi) {
    this.sD = sD;
    this.sS = sS;
    this.sL = sL;
    this.sM = sM;
    this.sCo = sCo;
    this.sCa = sCa;
    this.sNe = sNe;
    this.sNi = sNi;
}
public datosDelDomicilio(EditText etD, EditText etNi, EditText etNe, EditText etCa, EditText etCo, EditText etM, EditText etL, EditText etS) {
    this.etD = etD;
    this.etNi = etNi;
    this.etNe = etNe;
    this.etCa = etCa;
    this.etCo = etCo;
    this.etM = etM;
    this.etL = etL;
    this.etS = etS;
}
public String[] getOpc() {
    return opc;
}
public void setOpc(String[] opc) {
    this.opc = new String[]{"1.Correcto","2.Incorrecto","3.No se localizó"};
}
public String getsT() {
    return sT;
}
public void setsT(String sT) {
    this.sT = sT;
}
public Spinner getsD() {
    return sD;
}
public void setsD(Spinner sD) {
    this.sD = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerDistrito);
}
public Spinner getsS() {
    return sS;
}
public void setsS(Spinner sS) {
    this.sS = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSeccion);
}
public Spinner getsL() {
    return sL;
}
public void setsL(Spinner sL) {
    this.sL = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocalidad);
}
public Spinner getsM() {
    return sM;
}
public void setsM(Spinner sM) {
    this.sM = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerManzana);
}
public Spinner getsCo() {
    return sCo;
}
public void setsCo(Spinner sCo) {
    this.sCo = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerColonia);
}
public Spinner getsCa() {
    return sCa;
}
public void setsCa(Spinner sCa) {
    this.sCa = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCalle);
}
public Spinner getsNe() {
    return sNe;
}
public void setsNe(Spinner sNe) {
    this.sNe = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerNe);
}
public Spinner getsNi() {
    return sNi;
}
public void setsNi(Spinner sNi) {
    this.sNi = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerNi);
}
public EditText getEtD() {
    return etD;
}
public void setEtD(EditText etD) {
    this.etD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
public EditText getEtNi() {
    return etNi;
}
public void setEtNi(EditText etNi) {
    this.etNi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}
public EditText getEtNe() {
    return etNe;
}
public void setEtNe(EditText etNe) {
    this.etNe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
}
public EditText getEtCa() {
    return etCa;
}
public void setEtCa(EditText etCa) {
    this.etCa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
}
public EditText getEtCo() {
    return etCo;
}
public void setEtCo(EditText etCo) {
    this.etCo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
}
public EditText getEtM() {
    return etM;
}
public void setEtM(EditText etM) {
    this.etM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
}
public EditText getEtL() {
    return etL;
}
public void setEtL(EditText etL) {
    this.etL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
}
public EditText getEtS() {
    return etS;
}
public void setEtS(EditText etS) {
    this.etS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
}
public ArrayAdapter<String> getAaOption() {
    return aaOption;
}
public void setAaOption(ArrayAdapter<String> aaOption) {
    this.aaOption = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opc);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos_del_domicilio);
    getsD().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsD().setAdapter(getAaOption());
    getsS().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsS().setAdapter(getAaOption());
    getsL().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsL().setAdapter(getAaOption());
    getsM().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsM().setAdapter(getAaOption());
    getsCo().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsCo().setAdapter(getAaOption());
    getsCa().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsCa().setAdapter(getAaOption());
    getsNe().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsNe().setAdapter(getAaOption());
    getsNi().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getsNi().setAdapter(getAaOption());
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch(parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinnerDistrito:
            sT = getsD().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtD().setEnabled(true);
                getEtD().setFocusable(true);
                getEtD().setCursorVisible(true);
                getEtD().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerSeccion:
            sT =getsS().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtS().setEnabled(true);
                getEtS().setFocusable(true);
                getEtS().setCursorVisible(true);
                getEtS().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerLocalidad:
            sT=getsL().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtL().setEnabled(true);
                getEtL().setFocusable(true);
                getEtL().setCursorVisible(true);
                getEtL().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerManzana:
            sT=getsM().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtM().setEnabled(true);
                getEtM().setFocusable(true);
                getEtM().setCursorVisible(true);
                getEtM().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerColonia:
            sT= getsCo().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtCo().setEnabled(true);
                getEtCo().setFocusable(true);
                getEtCo().setCursorVisible(true);
                getEtCo().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerCalle:
            sT=getsCa().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtCa().setEnabled(true);
                getEtCa().setFocusable(true);
                getEtCa().setCursorVisible(true);
                getEtCa().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerNe:
            sT=getsNe().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtNe().setEnabled(true);
                getEtNe().setFocusable(true);
                getEtNe().setCursorVisible(true);
               getEtNe().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerNi:
            sT=getsNi().getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sT.equals("2.Incorrecto")) {
                //Aquí si el spinner nos dice que es incorrecto habilitamos editText para ingresar los datos correctos al mismo tiempo validamos el envio de la información a la tabla Datos del Domicilio de la Base de datos
                getEtNi().setEnabled(true);
                getEtNi().setFocusable(true);
                getEtNi().setCursorVisible(true);
                getEtNi().setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
            }
         break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
public void onEnableEditText(View view){
    Button button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setEnabled(true);
        int count=0;
            if(getEtD().getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count+=1;
            }
            if(getEtS().getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count+=1;
            }
            if(getEtL().getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count+=1;
            }
            if(getEtM().getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count+=1;
            }
            if(getEtCo().getText().toString().trim().length()>0) {
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count += 1;
            }
            if(getEtCa().getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count+=1;
            }
            if(getEtNe().getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count+=1;
            }
            if(getEtNi().getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                //si esta lleno el respectivo campo el contador suma uno
                count+=1;
            }
        if(count==8){
            //Aqui validamos que todos los editText no vayan vacios, y procedemos a la siguiente activity_caracteristicas_del_domicilio.xml
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, caracteristicasDelDomicilio.class);
                startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

**Nota:** 
Es un proyecto pensado para una api de 25 en adelante...

Comment: Hola, cual es el spiner que debe crear ese evento? y creo que tus variables deberian ser un poco mas descriptivas para que den un significado por si solas,

Comment: En el constructor envías variables de Spinners, ¿de donde provienen? ,  ¿Estas tratando de alguna forma  instanciar esta clase? comenta en tu pregunta por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estaría mejor si usas el position que se encuentra  en el método del spinner, eso te ayuda a tener mejor control en cuanto a la selección del elemento en lugar de comparar con texto y respecto a tu pregunta, lo mejor (creo yo) seria tener un edittext (debajo de cada spinner) en enable = false por default y cambié true o false según lo que escoja el usuario, y pues validar todos tus edditext si tienen texto (lo puedes hacer en un solo if, no ocupas contador) y mostrar un botón de siguiente si cumple (si no cumplen con esto, que no aparezca) o que si se muestre pero al darle clic hacer la validación que quieres con eso decidirá si va a la siguiente actividad o le manda un mensaje (toast de preferencia) diciéndole el porque no pudo avanzar.

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:hint="Algo más aquí..."
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

editText2.setEnabled(true);
```

y como dijo Igmer: "tus variables deberían ser un poco mas descriptivas para que den un significado por si solas", es un buen consejo, piensa en el otro programador, que cuando este vea tu código lo entienda rápidamente. También un consejo más, no fuerces al usuario a ir a otra activity sin avisarle para eso es lo del botón que te comente arriba.

Bueno, esto es lo que yo entendí de tu pregunta, espero si sea de ayuda sino explícanos con más detalles para que nosotros podamos ayudarte. Saludos.